# Add children on expand in TreeViewer

Tags: java, jface

I have a TreeViewer which has elements with children which I want to fetch from a rest api, so initially there are no children for the nodes. What I currently did is I added a doubleClickListener to the nodes and fetch the children for the selected node, then use the treeviewer's method "expandToLevel" to show them. I want to be able to do that by clicking on the expand arrow too.

```
public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
        Module m = (Module) selection.getFirstElement();
        //----> theChildren are fetched here <---
        m.setStrings(theChildren);
        treeViewer.expandToLevel(m, 1);
    }
```

Unfortunately when I try to do it with the treeListener the getChildren method from the content provider is called first and therefore returns that there are no children. Is it ok to make the api call in the getChildren method?

```
        treeViewer.addTreeListener(new ITreeViewerListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent event) {                
            Module m = (Module) event.getElement();
            //----> theChildren are fetched here <---
            m.setStrings(theChildren);
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: You might want to look at using the `SWT.VIRTUAL` flag for the tree and `ILazyTreeContentProvider` for the content provider

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I don't know if its the best one out there but it works.
In treeExpanded I added async call to the expand of treeViewer so the children are shown now.

```
Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                
    @Override
    public void run() {
        treeViewer.expandToLevel(m, 1);
                    
    }
});
```